# How to have page background visible in a nested div or form input field

Tags: html, css

I am making a form with transparent input fields such that the body background is visible in the fields while the form has a solid background color.

Also, similar effect is needed to create a photo-frame kind of thing which has an outer div with solid background color and a transparent inner div through which the page background is visible.

Here is the markup for the photo-frame using two DIVs :

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body { background-image: url('http://nuwen.net/wallpaper/background4.png'); }

.outer {
    display: flex;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.inner {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Following image shows what I need to achieve. It seems as if the input fields created hole in the form container layer. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byz7IT6HpkQ0NHJuNFJheG1tcU0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you provide an image of the result you are trying to reach?

Comment: Just provide a link as a text.

Comment: It's not easy to imagine the resulting image. So, it's hard to give you an answer. May be you could not do it at all in your particular case or may be you have to take some restrictions and do this with a lot of work. Or just simplify your goal and solve the question much simpler. It highly depends on the expecting result.

Comment: Have not tested this but try setting the opacity to 0.0

Comment: You'd need some kind of background-clip to do what I think you're trying to do and I'm fairly sure its not possible with form elements.

Answer (score 0):

For your form  or form container, put this CSS in style

```
background : rgba(0,0,0,0)
```

or if you want to use different shade use value between in 0.0 to 1

like

```
 background : rgba(0,0,0,0.4)
```

EIDT CODE :

```
.form-container { 
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

EDIT CODE 2 :

css :

```
.input-container { 
      background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    }
```

HTML :

```
<div class="input-container">
<input type="text" name="">
</div>
```

Comment: This is of no use to me as it makes the whole form container transparent. I want it to be solid and only the fields to be transparent. But making field background to be transparent any way shows the form background color in it.

Comment: Then your can define same class for your form input

Comment: As I said, setting transparency in any way to the form field does not makes the form container layer below it as transparent.